# Dimension xml, unable to build "error: 'float|fraction' is an invalid format."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

After updating android studio to 3.0 and updating build tool version from `'25.0.0'` to `'26.0.2'`, I'm getting this error msg 'float|fraction' is an invalid format.   Basically unable to build the code.
          My dimen item is:
 `<item name="default_key_width" format="float|fraction" type="dimen">10%p</item>`.
     Need some workaround. Also if I change `float|fraction` to `float` then I get error msg as *invalid type: dimen*. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it 10.0 creates some problem. Solved it by removing format and replacing %p with only %.

```
    <item name="default_key_width" type="dimen">10%</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`10.0`** instead of **`10%p`**.

```
<item name="default_key_width" format="float" type="dimen">10.0</item>
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-RUN`**.

Comment: @PPB set `10.0` and remove `fraction`